# Image aspect ratio swift ios

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7.1beta

So, I'm learning iOS Swift. I'm going by some tutorials, and I'm stucked at image positioning.

I'm trying to figure out how uploaded picture is rescaled and positioned.Since I cannot post the screenshot, image that should be shown in my simulator as whole, I can only see like 25% of the picture. Should I change something in Attributes or in Size Inspector?

What I did so far (clearly wrong), was setting Intrinsic Size field -> select Placeholder, w/h = 320.

Then, I pinned and selected Aspect Ratio.

Any help, please? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can set the frame in code, image.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,10,10), you also can control drag to set width and height auto layout constraints.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to make sure an image fills a UIImageView:

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

You may also need to set constraints if you placed your image view in interface builder.
[image]

It's not entirely clear from your question how you want it positioned, but hopefully these get you on the right path.

Comment: Here is the screenshot:

http://postimg.org/image/g3577ikjb/


As you can see from it, my photo should "shrink" to fit the screen... I cannot explain it better. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to set up some constraints in interface builder. Based on your screenshot I'd probably add a top constraint and both side margins (which will keep it centered and full width - also set aspect ratio so it scales proportionally. Something like: http://prntscr.com/8jo1u5

Comment: Thanks... I'm trying, with no success. But will succeed, I hope.